# Doctrine ORM default value of none existing entity

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, composite-primary-key, composite-key

Lets say we have entities which are named `Element`, those MAY belong to a entity called `Layout`. Elements and Layouts have a `ManyToOne` relation, where Many Elements belong to one `Layout`.

The databas engine used is MySQL, additionally we use a unique key, which the `layout_id` is a part of. So therefore we have in the `Elements` table, a column called `layout_id` which can not be `null` (because of the composite unique key), and has a default of `0`. The value of `0` is a magic value and treated as 'No Layout assigned' throughout the code base (there are no FK's between `Element` and `Layout` because of this).

The problem with Doctrine ORM is that it tries to load a Layout with a ID of `0`, which it can not find because it does not exists. We can not create a `Layout` entry with ID `0` because `Layouts` have other foreign keys and there own other constraints.

Is there any suggestion on how to overcome this. Basically when the `layout_id` in the `Element` is `0`, we would like not to load a `Layout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case you cannot set this `layout_id` as part of the composite key. This is because of the foreign key constraint. Either your `layout_id` has to be `nullable` (meaning it cannot be part of the composite key) or you have to make a row in your `layout` table with id 0 (so it can be used as an identifier).

A solution could be to not use a composite key but instead add a primary key column for uniquely identifying your entity (surrogate key).